# A man tells his wife he is like a badger

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the following book, of which I remember a certain side plot (this was not the main plot of the book). The book is probably classified as fantasy, and was taking place in some medieval world. I read it in this decade, but I don't remember if it was new.

A king has been imprisoned for twenty years in another kingdom, and during this time he has become a philosopher and a poet. Meanwhile at home, his son has grown to be an adult. The king also has a warden at home, who tells his wife that one day the king will return, and he is waiting as patiently as a badger.

The king is then freed and returned to his kingdom. He writes a letter to his son, telling him he is now a philosopher and a poet. His son's wife thinks they should get rid of the king so that the son could rule the kingdom. But the son is just happy to get his father back. Once the king returns, the warden becomes a nobleman of some sort, and chooses badger as his insignia.

Comment: Can you recall any fantastic elements, or could this simply have been a mundane story set in a Medieval-European-type world?

Comment: @Adamant This book has at least been in the fantasy section of the library, because I have never read any medieval-style books outside that.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, if you can recall any fantasy elements from the story, that would be helpful, both for the purposes of identifying it, and since questions that aren’t about speculative fiction are not on-topic.

Comment: I laughed at the title. ***"Hello the wife. I'm a lot like a badger, don't'cha'know".***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Katherine Kerr's *[Darkspell](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/438190.Darkspell)*, the imprisoned King in question being 'Mael the Seer'.  The repeated phrase it "[I'm like a badger. I hold on](https://books.google.com/books?id=30qYi_KsbmsC&pg=PT241&lpg=PT241&dq=darkspell%20badger&source=bl&ots=rjSEjJroiv&sig=HKKnNxlfQMGUVb5w16ADXmBnbRQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi--IyWsazQAhXq4IMKHexFDQQQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=badger&f=false)".